# #CodeIgniter Sending each "checked" check box values from multiple checkboxes to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, checkbox

***I have populated check boxes from database as follows...***

View:

```
<div class="control-group warning">  
<label for="room_number" class="control-label">Room Number: </label>
    <div class="controls">
    <?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $row): { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="room_number" id="room_number" value="<?php echo $row['room_number'];?>" style="margin:10px" /><?php echo $row['room_number'];?><br>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo form_error('room_number'); ?>
    </div>    
</div>
```

****Now when user submits the form, I need to populate the database table, with each row for a "checked" checkbox. However, the code/ method below only submits a single row.****

Controller:

```
foreach($this->input->post('room_number') as $rm){ // 118
        $newReservation = array (
            'guest_id' => $guest_id,
            'room_number' => $this->input->post('room_number'),
            'room_type' => $this->input->post('room_type'),
            'meal_type' => $this->input->post('meal_type'),
            'extra_beds' => $this->input->post('ext_beds'),
            'purchases' => 0,
            'guest_count' => $this->input->post('number_of_guests'),
            'checkin' => $this->input->post('start_date'),
            'checkout' => $this->input->post('end_date'),
            'duration' => $this->input->post('reservation_duration'),
            'total' => $this->input->post('total'),
            'guest_status' => $this->input->post('guest_status'),
            'payment_status' => 'Pending',
            'travel_agent' => $token,
            'time_stamp' => $now
        );
        $this->group_reservations_model->populate_new_reservations_table($newReservation);
```

Model:

```
    function populate_new_reservations_table($newReservation) {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->insert_batch('reservations', $newReservation);

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        return true;
    }
}
```

***It returns following error:***

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: controllers/group_reservations.php

Line Number: 118

Comment: Figured it out! http://paste.ubuntu.com/5960145/

Comment: try this helper class  https://github.com/nu1ww/ci_multiple_checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple checkboxes with the same name. Use `name="room_number[]"` istead of `name="room_number"`.

Good luck ;)